# Clearing browser cache to prevent form resubmission

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a forum page using CodeIgniter (new to this) but once the user submits a comment and refreshes the page, the comment is re-submitted upon clicking "Continue" to the "Confirm Form Re submission" prompt.

I added the following to the method of the controller, but the post data in the browser cache isn't cleared.

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

Giving a perfect answer with the amount of information present would be very hard but I can tell you that you need to redirect the user after the page submit to another page so that upon refresh, the page wont resubmit.

> Please refer [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything "wrong", but in terms of the browser if you post a request and then refresh it (either a POST or a GET request) it will re send the request.

To avoid this sort of behaviour (in any framework or app) I would recommend that each "submit" be actually part of 2 request, one that submits the information, and that one redirects to a presentation of the result.

For example, lets say you have a post message handler (controller method) and a view of comments handler (controller method).
Then the user enters the view comments page, it fills a new comment and post not to the same page, but to the create method page/controller/method and that one instead of displaying anything it actually redirects to the original page where the result will be seen.

So, something like this:

- `/comments` receive GET requests and shows list of comments
- inside `/comments` page there is a form to enter a new comment, this form's action does a POST to `/comment/add`
- `/comment/add` receives POST request, it creates a new comment and then redirects back to `/comments`, it doesn't display any HTML, just does redirect

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good answer, but with today's UX designs, users want to be able to do all their activities within a single page (Basically less clicks to reach a functionality). Another method I am contemplating is the use of a modal form to handle comment posting which will also handle the process and close on success. What do you think?

Comment: Hi, yes, definitely you could go for an AJAX option on a modal form.
Although, post requests to a different URL and then redirecting back will not necessary affect the UX perception. You don't need exactly AJAX to have a great UX (neither you have a great UX by having AJAX), the UX will be good or bad because on how do you plan the interaction and usability of your application. But sure, by all means go with AJAX :)